# Should I move a temporary into a variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, c++14

If I have an existing non-trivial variable and I want to re-assign it with new contents that I will declare on the same line as the assignment, should I use move semantics?

My question comes from the following scenario:

```
std::vector<string> existing = { ... };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    const char *bunch_of_strings = ... ;
    std::stringstream ss(bunch_of_string);

    existing = std::move(std::vector<std::string>(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), {}));
}
```

should I be doing this, will the compiler optimize it similarly if I don't, or is it just better not to?

Comment: What did your profiler report to you? Normally I wouldn't even consider the performance of the above listed code unless the code was highlighted by either VTune, Instruments or Dtrace as a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @AhiyaHiya I'm more interested in how the compiler treats it, and whether it is good/bad practice; as in, if the compiler will turn it into a move instruction anyway. So performance isn't my main concern here.

Comment: In this specific case, you should use `existing.assign(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), {});`, which has the same result, but reuses the capacity already allocated in `existing`. (See [`std::vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) overload #2)

Comment: @Casey this was discussed in the comments of user2485710's answer. It seems to be debatable, but I definitely agree with you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`std::move` is redundant there. The purpose of `move` is to treat a variable as a temporary (more accurately, an rvalue) when it's not (or might not be). If it's already an rvalue, it will certainly be moved if possible anyway.

Comment: That's how I generally use `move` (of course), but I wasn't exactly sure when it comes to how the compiler treats these cases. After reading about copy-elision I get a good idea.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Copy elision applies when a temporary is moved into some other newly-initialized object. It doesn't apply here because the vector is getting assigned, not initialized. Anyway, the compiler always knows when something is an rvalue, based on the form of the expression. The move is already guaranteed simply based on the use of "constructor call" syntax, period.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Believe it or not, I'm actually trying to write a compiler at the moment :L But don't worry, I;m not going anywhere near translation to assembly or optimization until I've read a hell of a lot of theory and got my parser/lexer well up to scratch haha.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most appropriate way to construct that object for that vector is to use `emplace_back` aka you just create that object in place, you don't copy, you don't move, you just create that thing right were it's supposed to be in the first place .

[`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)

Comment: But my `vector` isn't guaranteed to be empty. Now that we're talking about performance, how expensive do you think a `clear()` then `emplace_back()` for all elements would be given highest level of optimization?

Comment: Also, I would have thought that `assign()` is the most appropriate way.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode `emplace_back` constructs your object after the last element ( if any ); it doesn't really matter if your vector is empty or not. I also think that the most effective way to clear an array in C++11 and beyond is to swap with an empty one, you have `std::vector<T> vec;` you clear `vec` with `vec.swap(std::vector<T>{})`.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode `assign` is not that flexible at all, look closer, it's probably only useful when you have a sequence of elements that repeats itself over and over, I can't see any practical use for `assign` honestly .

Comment: In this case, all it can do is make copies though. The underlying structure of a `stringstream` isn't guaranteed to be suited for moving into a `vector` so you have to copy each individual element into it. This seems like a great case for `vector::assign()`.

Comment: Why do you think swapping with an empty vector would be more efficient than clearing? I'm sure the standard library implementers would have optimized `vector::clear()` as best possible.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode : `clear` won't reduce capacity, merely erase elements.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode all I know is that I wouldn't do that, I would do what I suggested, there is also to consider that the implementation of the strings and related classes is highly subject to variation among different implementations, you get `libc++`, `msvc` and `libstdc++` that are basically implementing this kind of types in different ways, most of the time said implementation is not even "standard", there are libraries that still use the "copy on write" technique which is now illegal in the standard. You should benchmark this stuff and try 2-3 variations to see what fits best.

Comment: @ildjarn then an optimization could be that it simply reduces `length()` and any references to objects past that would be invalidated upon an `emplace` or `push`

Comment: @CoffeeandCode as ildjarn said, when using `clear` you are still holding on your memory, you are keeping your memory taxed by your empty vector without any good reason, a swap with an empty vector will just clear and release the memory all at once and it's a clear piece of code to read .

Comment: @ildjarn very true, but then that is memory optimization not performance optimization; I have plenty of memory in my case

Comment: @user2485710 but then I have to reallocate memory for every element that I `emplace`, so it's vague to say that it is a memory 'tax' if I still need some or even more of it.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode memory is basically 90% of your performances, a modern CPU is almost all about moving memory/data . Just benchmark this stuff, the suggestion has been given, the implementations of strings and streams are highly subject to what your vendor has given to you, try it out and see .

Comment: @user2485710 exactly, and memory allocations aren't the cheapest operations on the block.